# Conditional pivoting on MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with structure and data like below. Basically, one object can have multiple latitude and longitude values. I want to write a query that gets each lat/long pair for an object in the same row.

```
meta_id (PK) | object_id | key         | value
1            | 1         | latitude_0  | 10
2            | 1         | longitude_0 | 100
3            | 1         | latitude_1  | 11
4            | 1         | longitude_1 | 111
5            | 1         | latitude_2  | 12
6            | 1         | longitude_2 | 122
```

The query result would be,

```
object_id | latitude | longitude
1         | 10       | 100
1         | 11       | 111
1         | 12       | 122
```

The tricky part is that there can be an arbitrary number of lat/long pairs so I cant hardcode the query. A object could have 1 pair or it could have 40 pairs. I can get the result easily enough by hardcoding the `JOINs` but that obviously isn't what I am looking for. I've copied my current query below, but it is unable to pair up the appropriate key indicies, e.g. it matches `latitude_0` with `longitude_0`, `longitude_1`, and `longitude_2`.

```
SELECT p1.key, p1.value, p2.key, p2.value
FROM page_meta2 AS p1
    INNER JOIN page_meta2 AS p2 ON 
        p1.object_id = p2.object_id AND 
        p1.meta_id != p2.meta_id
WHERE p1.object_id = 1   -- will be parameter in final query (e.g. ?)
    AND p1.key LIKE 'latitude%'
    AND p2.key LIKE 'longitude%'
```

---

#### Replicate my environment

Script to replicate my environment is:

```
CREATE TABLE `page_meta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `object_id` (`object_id`),
  KEY `key` (`key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `page_meta` ( `object_id`, `key`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1,'latitude_0', '10'),
    (1,'longitude_0','100'),
    (1,'latitude_1', '11'),
    (1,'longitude_1','111'),
    (1,'latitude_2', '12'),
    (1,'longitude_2','122'),
    (2,'latitude_0', '20'),
    (2,'longitude_0','200'),
    (2,'latitude_1', '21'),
    (2,'longitude_1','211'),
    (2,'latitude_2', '22'),
    (2,'longitude_2','222');
```

Comment: I would fix this broken design

Comment: I would suggest having the lat/long in the same record.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. Unfortunately, I cannot change the schema. Hence, my question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use mysql's [substring_index()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function in the join condition to get the number after the `_` character, therefore match the lat / long pairs:

```
SELECT p1.object_id, p1.value as lat, p2.value as long
FROM page_meta2 AS p1
    INNER JOIN page_meta2 AS p2 ON 
        p1.object_id = p2.object_id AND 
        substring_index(p1.key, '_', -1) = substring_index(p2.key, '_', -1)
WHERE p1.object_id = 1   -- will be parameter in final query (e.g. ?)
    AND p1.key LIKE 'latitude%'
    AND p2.key LIKE 'longitude%'
```

Comment: Thats pretty clever. Hopefully it will perform well. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: No, this is not really a performant solution. It would be better if you split the type and the numbering into 2 separate fields.